# Can Mac Messages connect to more than one apple id?

Tags: messages, accounts

Say I have two iCloud accounts, personal@example.com and work@example.com. My iPhone is logged into personal@example.com, while the Messages app on my work computer is logged into work@example.com.

Is there a way to get text messages on the Messages app? I've tried going to "Messages > Preferences > Accounts > **+**" to add an account, but the only option seems to be Jabber.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up two iCloud accounts on a mac.
In System Preferences you can go to Internet Accounts, there you can see al your accounts, and you can easily add another iCloud account.
[image: internet accounts]
You can then select what you would like to use with the new iCloud account, keep in mind though that only one of the iCloud accounts can be used for photo stream at a time.
[This answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3849614?start=0&tstart=0) on the apple support community site also explains it.

Comment: Yes, I've already set up a second iCloud account. But Messages isn't in the list of things I can use it for. Just Mail, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders. I think that Messages has its own account management scheme and doesn't use system preferences. I also think that this might be deliberate -- they want Messages to be unambiguously attached to just a single iPhone, which means just a single iCloud account.

Comment: At any rate, I "fixed" it by logging Messages out of my work iCloud account and into my personal iCloud account.